# JOIN on bigint[] doesn't return the field with array of populated objects

Tags: sql, postgresql

## Edit

I ended up doing the following:

```
SELECT
    u.*,
    temp.json_data as roles
FROM my_schema.user as u
CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT jsonb_agg(
        json_build_object(
            'id', r.id,
            'role_name', r.role_name
        )
    ) as json_data
    FROM UNNEST(u.roles) as fkl(id)
    INNER JOIN my_schema.role as r
        ON r.id = fkl.id
) as temp
WHERE u.user_name = 'John'
```

---

I have a couple of tables that look like this,

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS my_schema.role (
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    role_name VARCHAR (255) UNIQUE NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS my_schema.user (
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    user_name VARCHAR (255) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    roles BIGINT[] NOT NULL
);
```

Suppose I have the following records in each:

```sql
-- user
id       user_name       roles
 1       'Mike'          [1, 3]
 2       'John'          [3]
```

```sql
-- role
id       role_name
 1       admin
 2       super
 3       common
```

I want to join these two tables, here's the query:

```
SELECT
    u.*
FROM my_schema.user u
LEFT JOIN my_schema.role r
    ON r.id = ANY(u.roles)
WHERE u.user_name = 'John'
```

But this returns the following:

```
{
  id: 2,
  user_name: 'John',
  roles: [ '3' ]
}
```

Why does this not populate the `roles` field? I'd expect the following output:

```
{
  id: 2,
  user_name: 'John',
  roles: [
    {
      id: 3,
      role_name: 'common'
    }
  ]
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I just need to pull out everything from `my_schema.user`, so I use `u.*`

Comment: Why miraculously? I do a join on `my_schma.role`. It kind of works too, if I do `SELECT u.*, r.role_name . . .`, the result includes a `role_name` field with the value `common`.

Comment: The problem, is that if I have multiple roles, it only returns the first one

Comment: So how should I do this? `SELECT u.*, r.role_name as roles FROM my_schema.user u LEFT JOIN my_schema.role r ON r.id = ANY(u.roles) WHERE u.user_name = 'John'` ? I've tried this, it doesn't return quite what I need it to

Comment: Yeah, I'm not going to do that. Anyway, I updated the question

Comment: If you have anything useful to contribute to this question, other than saying "that's a bad answer", please do so, to help visitors with similar cases in the future.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "fix the wrong information" in my question. The query I came up with returns exactly what I expect, so perhaps if you elaborate, I'd be able to accommodate your request.

Comment: I've updated the OP

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=45c38378522a023c641202432fab1224

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your query.

Just join `role` table on existence of `role.id` in unnested `user.roles` and aggregate it values in json, like this

```
SELECT
    u.*,
    jsonb_agg(
        json_build_object(
            'id', r.id,
            'role_name', r.role_name
        )
    ) as json_data
FROM my_schema.user as u
JOIN my_schema.role as r ON r.id IN (
    SELECT
        UNNEST(roles)
    FROM my_schema.user ur 
    WHERE ur.id = u.id
)
WHERE u.user_name = 'John'
GROUP BY u.id
```

Or even without subquery, like this

```
SELECT
    u.*,
    JSONB_AGG(
        JSON_BUILD_OBJECT(
            'id', r.id,
            'role_name', r.role_name
        )
    ) AS json_data
FROM my_schema.user u
JOIN my_schema.role r ON ARRAY[r.id::bigint] @> u.roles
WHERE u.user_name = 'John'
GROUP BY u.id
```

By the way, why are you using `BIGINT` array to store `roles` values in `user` table, if `role.id` is of a `serial` type, not a `bigserial`? If you make `roles` to be of a type `INT[]`, than the casting `r.id::bigint` in `JOIN` condition could be removed.